# setState after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have the following code in which I get the current state of `year`, which changes when you press a button in the main component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        this.setState({
            update: true
        });
        if(nextProps.year===2019){
            console.log('oneeeeeee',this.state.update)
            this.setState({
                dates: ['09.2018', '10.2018', '11.2018', '12.2018'],
                numbers: ['3000', '4000', '3300', '2700'],
            },() => {
                this.setState({update: false})
            });
        } 
    }
```

The problem is that I work with a schedule that catches every button click in the menu itself, and re-draws the schedule when I click it.

If I remove the `update` property, everything works fine. Each time, when changing the `year`, I assign an `update` to `true`, and transfer to it new data. After that, I want to transfer to the `update: false`

Tell me, please, how can I transfer `false` to `update`, only after I transferred the data to `dates` and `numbers`?

I tried to use callback, but it does not work. Thanks for any of your tips!

Comment: It's expected that state updates can be performed in batch. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. Where `update` is used and why is it necessary? There could be more convenient approach.

Comment: I understood you correctly, you mean that everything should have time to transmit, and if I submit `update:false` immediately after `numbers`, everything will work, so the problem is in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things that you need to correct.

First: First, setState is async and batched and hence calling setState for `update: true` and would update the state immediately

Second: You must always compare current and nextProps in before executing anything in componentWillReceiveProps

Third: `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated since v16.3.0 and hence I recomment you use `componentDidUpdate` instead

Example using `componentWillReceiveProps`

```js
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if (nextProps.year !== this.props.year && nextProps.year === 2019) {
        this.setState({
            update: true
        }, () => {
            this.setState({
              dates: ['09.2018', '10.2018', '11.2018', '12.2018'],
              numbers: ['3000', '4000', '3300', '2700'],
            },() => {
                this.setState({update: false})
            });
        })
    }  
}
```